# a couple of questions, one of matrices (theoric) and another sort of related i.e linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is $2\times2$ matrix and $I$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix, which one of the following statement sabout the equation $A^2-A-2I=0$ is false?

a) $A=-I$ and $A=2I$ are solutions.

b) The only solutions are of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$.

c) $A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ are solutions.

d) The equation has more than four solutions.

So I was about to tick (d) at the exam, but I thought it may have infinite many solutions ... so I ticked (a) ...

This other one says as follows: two students find different solutions to a linear system, and call their solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$. For this way they conclude that the linear system must have infinite many solutions, which one of the following must also be a solution of the linear system?

a) $\frac12 x_1 + \frac12 x_2$

b) $2x_1$

c) $x_1+x_2$

d) $0$

and last one...

Let $A, D$ and $S$ be non zero square matrices related by $AS=SD$, and suppose $S$ is invertible. Which one of the following is false?

a) $D^3= S^{-1} A^3 S$

b) $[A]=[D]$

c) $A^3=S^{-1} D^3 S$

d) $A^3= S D^3 S^{-1}$

I went for d in this last one...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please...does anyone the answers to the questions above?

Comment: Since statements b) and d) can fairly easily seen to contradict each other, and you must tick the _one_ false statement, it must be one of those two...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Hints --

The first question: Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&x\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, where $x$ is *arbitrary*. Calculate $A^2-A-2I$.

The second question: Write the linear system as $Ax=b$, so that $Ax_1=Ax_2=b$. Just check which one of the four options must satisfy $Ax=b$.

The third question: Suppose "$[A]=[D]$" means "$A$ and $D$ are similar matrices". Then (b) is true because $AS=SD$ implies that $A=SDS^{-1}$ or $D=S^{-1}AS$. Also, with the latter two expressions, can you calculate $A^3$ and $D^3$?

Comment: Not even with hints I can figure it out..I wanted to mean by [A]=[D] that both have the same determinant which I know it has to be true..that's all far I can go..

Comment: I bet $[A] = [D]$ means $A$ and $D$ are similar matrices. Which they are.

Comment: you know the solutions..? I am so walking on the line between failing and passing.. I counted them all worng..so having at least one right will do a lot

Comment: @Maximilian1988 Which questions are you unable to solve even with hints? What are the exact difficulties you have?

Comment: @WillNelson Thanks. I've edited your suggestion into the answer.

Comment: @user1551 To be honest...all of them, it may be cause my brain right now is fried.. :S I may try again tomorrow, to understand everything, can you tell me though if any of my guesses at the exam were right? i.e : 1)a 2)c 3)a

Comment: @Maximilian1988 Sadly, the correct answers are 1)b, 2)a, 3)c.

Comment: oh no! well didn't count on them but thanks, I ll have a look at them tomorrow and see if I understand the whole problem. Thanks for your time and patience